# JQX Tree drag drop functionality still working on GUI after removing its code

Tags: jquery, jqxwidgets, jqwidget

I removed allowDrag attributre, and dragStart function from code, but JQX Tree drag drop functionality is appearing as working in GUI. I have deleted cache and cookies. How can I stop it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried by setting allowDrag to false?